# Conservative garbage collector

Tags: garbage-collection

I've seen garbage collectors labelled as a lot of things- generational, etc. But I've seen the Boehm GC labelled as "conservative". What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A garbage collector must scan all objects and invocations (execution stack) to identify all of the "live" addresses in the executing program and then "collect" objects that do not have "live" addresses.  In some environments it's possible for the GC algorithm to be PRECISE and know exactly what is an object address and what is not.  In other environments it must scan parts of storage (most notably the execution stack) where there are words of storage that MIGHT be an object address and make the CONSERVATIVE assumption that if it looks like a valid address, and there is an object that has that address, then the object should not be collected.

There are advantages to conservative collection, most notably that the code generator (if not interpreted) is freer to allocate variables where and when it needs them and it need not keep rigorous track of which are object pointers.  (The need to keep track of object pointer locations can lead to less well optimized code, in addition to making the code generator considerably more complex.  Also, a conservative collector stands some reasonable chance of being used with a compiler which was never intended to support garbage collection, while a precise collector would require that the compiler be radically altered.)

The major disadvantage of the conservative approach is that a full "copying" collector cannot be implemented.  When copying is done the pointers to the copied objects must be updated, and if it's not clear whether a given bit value is an object pointer or just a numeric value, it cannot be safely determined whether or not it should be modified when the object is copied.  There's also the disadvantage that some "dead" objects may end up not getting collected, due to random bit patterns that look like their addresses, though in practice this is not a serious concern.

Comment: A copying collector can be implemented if object references as stored as handles rather than direct pointers.  In the absence of hardware support, handle-based approaches are apt to be slower than ones which use direct pointers, but in multi-processor systems with hardware support, a handle-based approach could have advantages.  And of course they would have a huge advantage if one is trying to judge what might or might not be an object reference.

Comment: @supercat What kind of system has hardware support for this?

Comment: @Pepijn: I don't know of any existing hardware that would support such a thing without imposing a 16,384 object limit (which by today's standards would of course be ludicrously small).  If someone were designing a next-generation architecture with the intention of optimizing performance in object-oriented frameworks, however, it would be possible for a modest amount of hardware to provide considerable assistance with garbage-collection. For example, an important requirement in generational or concurrent garbage collection is to know what objects have been modified since...

Comment: ...the last time the GC examined them. In most architectures, trying to have any write to an object set a "touched" bit would add a huge amount of overhead, but a cache of recently-touched objects could greatly reduce that overhead. Additionally, a system that was designed to have one core perform garbage collection could have a set of global trap-range registers which was writable only by that core but visible to the rest; if the GC set a trap on the addresses associated with an object immediately before moving it, then any core which tried to access an object...

Comment: ...while it was in the process of being moved would trigger a trap [the trap code would then wait for the move to complete, update the address, and result].  While it wouldn't be possible to have perfectly deterministic GC performance, it would probably be possible to limit worst-case pauses for any actions that don't involve allocations.

Comment: Wait, I seem to recall this Java GC that was built on a platform with hardware write-barriers. Hmmmm.

Comment: Does Boehm GC implements sweep ?

Comment: @SaCi - Google it:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector - "The collector uses a mark-sweep algorithm"

Answer (score 9):

A conservative garbage collector is one that does not know whether or not a given word is a pointer. If the word points into an allocated heap block then the garbage collector conservatively assumes that the word is a pointer and, therefore, does not recycle that heap block or anything considered to be reachable from it.

The main advantage of this approach is that it can collect unreachable values without having to work in harmony with the compiler. However, there are many disadvantages:

1. Values that happen to look like pointers cause memory leaks by preventing parts of the heap from being recycled. This is a much bigger problem with 32-bit address spaces because almost every int will point to a heap block if GBs of RAM have been allocated.
2. Determining whether or not a word points into an allocated heap block requires the heap to be searched which is slow and (objectively) unnecessary.
3. The GC cannot move heap blocks because it cannot update pointers because it does not know where they all are.
4. Code that hides pointers or uses pointers outside the heap block will crash a conservative GC. This problem arose with the Numerical Recipes code and Boehm GC, albeit because the NR C code violated the C spec.

These disadvantages are severe enough that production garbage collectors try not to be conservative whenever possible.

Comment: Your point 2 is quite wrong.  In a properly designed setup determining if a pointer is addressing a valid allocation is quite efficient.

Comment: @HotLicks: Implementations usually search an interval tree which typically incurs several out-of-cache memory reads in the inner loop of the mark phase. That is slow compared to not having to do a search in an accurate collector.

Comment: The implementation I worked on did that much more efficiently.  For small objects similar sizes were in arrays so that the object boundary could be computed, and object validity could be checked against a bit vector per array.

Comment: @HotLicks: That's only part of the solution. Given a (possibly interior) pointer to an object of unknown type, how do you determine whether or not it is "small" and (if applicable) which such bitvector to check?

Comment: Interior pointers are poison in many schemes.  But determining if a bit pattern (interior or not) is *possibly* a pointer can generally be fairly efficiently done, by comparing to the limits associated with the bit vectors, indexing the appropriate one, and scanning for an object boundary.  Various tricks make this quite efficient.