# Garbage collection in a C compiled language

Tags: c, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a garbage collected language that is compiled to C and through that to assembly. Then, how garbage collection works when it is compiled down to C? Does it become fully deterministic? Or is it contained in the resulting program as another program that runs periodically and collects garbage? This is probably a very easy, if not silly, question but I wanted some clarifications.

Comment: What do you mean "compiled to C"?

Comment: Like scheme implementations that compile down to C, or nim implementation if I remember correctly that nim is garbage collected.

Comment: If I well understand C code is generated? In that case, if nobody knows the answer, maybe you can try to look at the generated C code of very simple programs.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. I assume you think of a language interpreter(?), compiler(?), that actually is written in C. Then what you call "garbage collection" would be the application's memory management routines.

Comment: It is true that things are not clear in my head. For example, in Java, JVM is around when you run your programs so garbage collection is also a part of it an runs occasionally. But how this would be achieved in a language that generates C code and through it assembly? Would memory management routines be embedded in generated C code?

Comment: @meguli They would required to be. If they were not, they would never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's compiling to C, such implementations typically link in a runtime library for the original language. That library contains the garbage collector for the higher-level language data. And the data structures used to represent the original language's data in C includes additional fields needed by the garbage collector.

Another technique they may use is [*conservative garbage collection*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629446/conservative-garbage-collector).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do something similar in a compiled language is done in iOS with ARC [reference counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).  It's technically not garbage collection but something similar.  You would need to periodically search your programs memory for addresses that had been allocated pointing to the heap to see if it was ok to free the memory or not.

Answer (score 0):

Bohem gc exists; however if you have an integer in the right range to be a pointer to a dead object entire graphs can leak. http://hboehm.info/gc/ In all a poor choice.